# Canvas scaler does not work when the UI is Instantiated at runtime

Tags: unity, mobile, scale, unity-ui

My canvas scaler does not work when the UI is instantiated dynamically.

It does work well in iPhone 6.5 inch simulator:

[image: Correct scaling behaviour]

The problem is when I use 5.5 inch or smaller simulator:

[image: Incorrect scaling behaviour]

It does not follow the Canvas scaler to resize.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set worldPositionStays to false as a second parameter to SetParent.

YourUI.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);

Comment: This answer would be even better if it briefly explained why this fixes the problem.